# Web Deploy setAcl Failure

Tags: build, tfs, permissions, acl, web-deployment

UPDATE:

To answer a recent comment...I found the following information but it didn't work.

1. Go to Programs and Features in the control panel.
2. Find the "Microsoft Web Deploy 3.0 Setup"
3. Right click the program and click "Change".
4. Out of the three options, choose "Change" from the "Change, repair, or remove installation menu."
5. Under the IIS Deployment Handler, there is an option that is usually unchecked, "Configure for Non-Administor Deployments".  Check this option and click next.
6. Finish installation.

This sets up additional options under the management delegation UI that should allow non-admin accounts to deploy to your application.  It works on one server but not another.  I ran out of time trying to get this to work.  My other solution was to do this:

- Builds are managed by a dedicated team.  We restricted the "View/Edit Build Definitions" on all projects in TFS.
- We let the build accounts remain as ADMINS.
- We kept the passwords in the definition.

Both solutions work, but I do prefer to the former.  One day I'll figure out the difference between the two servers and post another update.

Reference: http://workinghardinit.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/wdeployconfigwriter-account-issues-trouble-shooting-web-deploy-2-0-with-lessons-learned/

---

Going on three days of troubleshooting - I am officially stumped.

**Error Details from TFS Build Log**

> MSDeployPublish:
>
> Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to https://XX.XX.XX.XX:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=Default%20Web%20Site ...
>
> Starting Web deployment task from source:package(D:\Builds\Sources\ProjectA.zip) to Destination:auto().
>
> **Updating setAcl (Default Web Site/Test).**
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3847,5): error : Web deployment task failed.((2/19/2013 9:58:23 AM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.) [D:\Builds\Sources\ProjectA.csproj]
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3847,5): error :  [D:\Builds\Sources\ProjectA.csproj]
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3847,5): error : (2/19/2013 9:58:23 AM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer. [D:\Builds\Sources\ProjectA.csproj]
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3847,5): error : The server experienced an issue processing the request. Contact the server administrator for more information. [D:\Builds\Sources\ProjectAcsproj]
>
> **Publish failed to deploy.**
>
> Done Building Project "D:\Builds\Sources\ProjectA.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
>   Done Building Project "D:\Builds\Sources\ProjectWeb.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
>
> **Build FAILED.**

I have three environments.  Development, QA and Production

Development and QA has a non-production build account.  Production has a production build account.

The deployment works on one of the production servers and on all of the development and QA servers.  But not the other.  These are separate servers that host different web applications.  It is not load balanced or part of a web farm.

I believe this is a permission issue but this issue only exists on one of the servers.  To get this deployment to work, I have to setup the production **tfs build account on the box as an administrator**.  Or **GRANT FULL CONTROL to EVERYONE** on the web application folder.  Neither of which are preferred.  Not to mention none of the other servers are setup that way.

During the deployment I did notice the ACL permissions are wrong during the first steps of deployment.  The web application folder is granting the build account special permissions.  While on the other environments, that permission never gets set.  I have no clue why this is happening.  Perhaps it is an immediate step in the workflow, but I am not certain.

All feature delegation options are setup according [to this website](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/13/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy.aspx).  I know they are correct, because I have implemented it several times now.  What isn't specified in the link is allowing the build account on the feature rules.  All of that is set from the application to the top level site.

If I switch the QA build in TFS to deploy to production it fails with the same issues.  So it isn't the build definition.  If I grant admin or everyone rights then it works so it isn't the project or configuration.

**MSBuild Arguments**

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC
/p:MSDeployServiceUrl=https://XX.XX.XX.XX:8172/msdeploy.axd 
/p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site/Test"
/p:UserName=DOMAIN\ProdBuildAccount /p:Password=*******
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
```

The deployment is kicked off from Team Explorer after queuing a successfully build.

Also if I take the package.zip and import it manually into IIS then the ACL's are correct and it deploys perfectly.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: Yes and no.

I'll modify my original answer to include my findings since it is rather lengthy.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I ended up just adding the build identity to the Administrators group too. Wish I didn't have to do that though!